# LINQ TO Nhibernate Count

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I am trying to use LINQ to Nhibernate to get a count on a table in my database.  However, the code I am running is pulling back all of the records in the table versus running select count() from table.

Here's my code-

```
public int GetTotalCount(Func<T, bool> where) {

            IQueryable<T> queryable = this._sessionManager.GetCurrentSession().Linq<T>().Where(where).AsQueryable();
            return queryable.Count();

}
```

I also tried-

```
    public int GetTotalCount(Func<T, bool> where)
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = this._sessionManager.GetCurrentSession().Linq<T>();
        return queryable.Count(where);
    }
```

Both pull back the entire dataset versus running a count.  Any ideas?

Also, I'm using NHProf to profile it, so I can the query it is running, which is

select *
from table

Comment: What version of the Linq to NHibernate provider and NHibernate itself are you running?

Comment: Nhibernate.Linq - version 1.1.0.1001
Nhibernate - version 2.1.2.4000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `where` parameter needs to be an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`; otherwise you are loading everything in memory and using LINQ-to-objects.

In short:

```
public int GetTotalCount(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return _sessionManager
        .GetCurrentSession()
        .Linq<T>()
        .Where(where);
        .Count();
}
```

Comment: figured this out a couple days ago.  this is the issue.

Comment: Great answer! I was at a loss why my where clause was not translated to the query.

Comment: How would this then be used?